# Print line numbers after comparison

Tags: perl, compare

Can someone tell me the best way to print the number of different lines in 2 files. I have 2 directories with 1000s of files and I have a perl script that compares all files in dir1 with all files in dir2 and outputs the difference to a different file. Now I need to add something like Filename - # of different lines
File1 - 8
File2 - 30

Right now I am using

```
my $diff = `diff -y --suppress-common-lines "$DirA/$file" "$DirB/$file"`;
```

But along with this I also need to print how many lines are different in each one of those 1000 files.

Sorry is a duplicate of my prev thread. So would be glad if some moderator could delete the previous one

Comment: Have you tried this yourself yet?

Answer (score 1):

Why you even use perl?

```
for i in "$dirA"/*; do file="${i##*/}"; echo "$file - $(diff -y --suppress-common-lines "$i" "$dirB/$file" | wc -l)" ; done > diffs.txt
```